# Grails application.js not executing

Tags: javascript, grails, asset-pipeline, grails-plugin

I have a Grails (2.3.6) app, and have included the `asset-pipeline` plugin as a dependency. In my `Config.groovy`:

```
plugins {
    // Lots of other stuff

    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.7"
}
```

In `myapp/web-app/js/application.js` (generated for me by Grails), I have only the following single line of code:

```
alert("Hello!");
```

Then in my `grails-app/views/index.gsp`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <asset:javascript src="application.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

When I do a `grails run-app`, I don't see my JS `alert(...)` statement fire. Have I positioned my `application.js` file incorrectly? Have I configured the `asset-pipeline` plugin incorrectly? Anything else I'm doing wrong? I just want to see my alert box!

Additionally, following the "*put CSS at the top, and JS at the bottom*" convention, I was wondering if anyone could chime in as to how I could reposition the `application.js` to appear at the bottom of the `<body/>` tag. My understanding was that `asset-pipeline` assets only work inside of `<head/>`.

Comment: What do you see if you view-source of the rendered page? Do you see the js being included?

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore (+1) - no I don't see it included.

Answer (score 1):

Your static files go in grails-app/assets/. See [organization](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#organization) for the details.

Comment: Thanks @Ken (+1) - and what about the placement of JS at the bottom (see last paragraph)?

Comment: I'm on my iPad now, so a detailed answer would take me forever. See the docs section on manifests. You could have two js files with different manifests and put one in the head and one at the end of body.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html) for the asset-pipeline plugin your assets should be under the grails-app/assets/ directory structure. Each type of asset is under a sub folder as follows:

```
grails-app/assets/javascripts
grails-app/assets/images
grails-app/assets/stylesheets
```

Move your `application.js` into the javascripts directory for asset-pipeline to pick it up.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore (+1) - and what about the placement of JS at the bottom (see last paragraph)?

Comment: I haven't tried using it outside the head tag, however I suspect it will work outside of there. Give it a try and see if it renders the correct includes within your body (I suspect it will).

Comment: Interesting...thanks again @Joshua Moore (+1 again). But now, when I simply include `application.js` as an asset, it seems to be auto-injecting any JS file that is located under `assets/javascripts`...is this typical `asset-pipeline` behavior? Also, each included JS file is of the form: `<script src="/assets/<name>.js?compile=false type="text/javascript"></script>`. What is this `compile=false` param? What makes it false? How do I make it true?

Comment: I suggest you take a few minutes and read through the documentation. The compile=false is because you are running in development mode and by default it's not going to compile in development mode. You can however (see the docs) change that through a configuration setting. As far as it injecting all your js files, that's default behavior unless you setup bundles/modules. Again, this is all explained in the documentation.